# Convertir tipo de dato String a Numérico en JAVA APACHE POI

Tags: java, apache, jtable, apache-poi

El método pasa los datos de un *JTable* a una hoja de excel, se pasan correctamente pero todos se pasan como *String*, el objeto lo paso con un `ToString();`, por esa razón me parece se pasan en *String* todos.

Cuando especifico que quiero que una celda se convierta en dato numérico, por ejemplo si el registro es un cero, al pasarse a tipo numérico sale como 1148 y todos los que tengan ceros salen iguales, no se como hacer para que no se pierda el valor original ejemplo: **`456.56`** se convierta numérico correctamente en el archivo excel.

```
for (int m = 0; m < tablaDestino.getRowCount(); m++) {
    //creamos la fila y se va incrementando 
    Row row = sheet.createRow(j++); //el j++ va incrementando desde el 12 en adelante para posicionar bien mi jtable 
    //ciclo tomar datos de tabladestino y hacerles set en el archivo excel
    for (int k = 0; k < tablaDestino.getColumnCount(); k++) {
        org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell cell = row.createCell(k);
        if (tablaDestino.getValueAt(m, k) != null) {
            cell.setCellValue(tablaDestino.getValueAt(m, k).toString());
            //cell.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
        }
    }
```

El método pasa correctamente la tabla pero cuando pongo la línea de código que ahí se muestra para hacer los datos tipo numéricos se pierde el valor original y sale un valor numérico que no tiene nada que ver con el valor original que estoy pasando.

¿Qué puedo hacer para que funcione correctamente?

Comment: Si lo quieres numérico debes mandar un `double`, pero como usas `toString()`, mandas una cadena y resulta en texto.

Comment: Si entiendo que en caso que quiera que el dato sea numerico lo mande como double, pero no se como hacer para que en lugar que se pasen como toString(); se pasen numericos.

Comment: cuando agrego la linea de codigo CellTypeNUMERIC me convierte los datos con numeros a numeros pero con unos valores que no tienen nada que ver con los originales.

Comment: Sólo tú sabes el tipo original que retorna `getValueAt(m, k)`.